# Require() on jquery.dotdotdot multiple jquery Modules warning

Tags: jquery, dotdotdot

i have a project where i'm trying to load my JS dependencies through NPM instead of using CDNs, everything was going great until i hit the `jquery-dotdotdot` package apparently it depends on `jQuery` while in my app i'm loading `jquery`

It's effectively loading jQuery again and disregarding the one i already had set up on my project... I'm requiring it in my app.js file like this
`require('jquery-dotdotdot');`

And this is the warning i get

```
WARNING in ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* /Users/username/Webserver/proj-name/node_modules/jQuery/dist/jquery.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    /Users/username/Webserver/proj-name/node_modules/jquery-dotdotdot/src/jquery.dotdotdot.min.umd.js
* /Users/username/Webserver/proj-name/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
    Used by 4 module(s), i. e.
    /Users/username/Webserver/proj-name/node_modules/buble-loader/index.js!/Users/jonnyserra/Webserver/zona-astro/resources/assets/frontend/js/frontend.js
```